# Is there a way to review web pages with page breaks in print mode

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, printing

### Context

I understand from [this guide](https://www.sitepoint.com/css-printer-friendly-pages/#:%7E:text=to%20a%20PDF.-,Developer%20Tools,-The%20DevTools%20) that we can inspect and emulate print styles. However, as mentioned, **page breaks won't be shown**.

It would be useful to see possible page breaks such that we know exactly how multi-page content will be printed. I know we can see the print preview with page breaks if we just right-click and choose print, however, the inspector for this preview screen does not seem to be as functional as the one for normal web pages. For example, the "Select an element in the page to inspect it" button won't work.

### Question

Is there a way to emulate print styles (including page breaks)?